# Handling secure login page in protractor

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication, polymer, protractor

My team is working to use AngularJs and Polymer components for a new web app. I am looking into how to create a UI automation suite for this. After lots of research looks like Protractor may help me out here with some tweaks to handle Polymer. But, the current challenge is as follows -

1. I navigate to the app
2. As part of our company policy, the every web visit is validated (unless within same session). Here is how the validation works -

   - A login page (non-Anugular) page appears after one types the required url. Sign in with the credentials
   - Another intermediate page appears where it asks to wait for page to load or click a link to go to next page. Click the link
   - Url changes back to the original used in #1
     Note: These validation pages take hell lot of time to load (changes to different internal urls). Also, the validation is skipped sometimes (within same session or through some other logic)

I have been struggling to design a prototype to handle all these. I am also trying to use Page Object while designing the prototype. Here is what I have so far.

```
login.js
________________________________________________________

var currentUrl;
var lastChangedUrl;
var secureUrl = 'corplogin.ssogen2.corporate.company.com';
var getwayUrl = 'gateway.zscalertwo.net';


var loginSuite = function(driver) {
var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

    describe('Handle login', function() {

        /*afterEach(function() {
            //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        })*/

        //it('Login to security test', function(){

            //********** Wait for page to load/URL to change to secure login page ************
            driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                currentUrl = url;
            }).then(function() {
                driver.wait(function() {
                    return driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                        lastChangedUrl = url;
                        return url !== currentUrl;
                    });
                });
            }).then(function() {
                //********** login to secure page ************
                if (lastChangedUrl.indexOf(secureUrl) > -1  || lastChangedUrl.indexOf(getwayUrl) > -1) {
                    var element = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
                    element.sendKeys("Username");

                    element = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
                    element.sendKeys("password"); //Give password

                    element = driver.findElement(By.name("submitFrm"));
                    element.click();
                }
            }).then (function() {
                //********** page is slow. wait for page to load/URL to change ************
                driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                    currentUrl = url;
                }).then(function() {
                    driver.wait(function() {
                        return driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                            lastChangedUrl = url;
                            return url !== currentUrl;
                        });
                    });
                }).then (function() {
                    //********** Click on the link to to go to test page ***********

                    if (lastChangedUrl.indexOf(getwayUrl) > -1) {
                        var element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
                        console.log("before click............");
                        element.click();
                    } 

                    //********** page is slow. wait for page to load/URL to change ************
                    driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                        currentUrl = url;

                    }).then(function() {
                        driver.wait(function() {
                            return driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                                lastChangedUrl = url;
                                return url !== currentUrl;
                            });
                        });
                    })
                    .then (function() {
                        //return defer.promise;
                        //browser.pause();
                    }); 
                }, 60000);                  
            });
        //});
    }, 60000);

return defer.promise;
};

module.exports = loginSuite; 


 spec.js
___________________________________________________________________________

describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

var myUrl = 'http://<my test app url>/';
var driver = browser.driver;

beforeEach(function() {
    driver.get(myUrl);
});



it('should login', function() {

    loginSuite(driver)
        .then(
            function(){

                console.log("End of tests:");
                expect(driver.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(myUrl);

            });
});
```

The issue here -

My expectation here is to have the promise returns to spec.js after the secure login page is handled so that I can continue with other testing using the driver object. For the sake testing I am logging 'End of tests' message and doing a dummy validation. But, looks like those two lines don't get executed.

Login to the secure site works and I see page changes to original test page. I tested that with Browser.pause(). But, the logging 'End of test' never happens, nor the validation.

2. I need to handle the scenario where the secure login page doesn't appear. Not sure what adjustment I need to do in login.js page

Is my approach for page object and handling the promises wrong here? I am able to go to one step further on the test app page when all the code are placed under one js file instead of splitting them for page object. Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share with you the "polymer way" of solving your problem.
The code below use two elements to monitor the URL, the auth flow, the previous page visited and log the user in/out of the app

The first will bind to the origin route, so you can send the user back there

```
 <app-route
   route="{{route}}"
   pattern="/origin/:page"
   data="{{data}}"
   tail="{{subroute}}">
 </app-route>
```

The second will bind to the authPage, allowing you to show/hide the auth page.

```
  <app-route
   route="{{subroute}}"
   pattern=":authPage"
   data="{{data}}
   active="{{authPageActive}}">
 </app-route>
```

**User auth, monitoring and page redirecting** 
Use the element: `<firebase-auth>` 
Is the user singned in?: `signedIn="{{isSignedIn}}"`

```
<firebase-auth id="auth" user="{{user}}" provider="google" on-
error="handleError" signedIn="{{isSignedIn}}"></firebase-auth>
```

Add an observer

```
observers: [
    '_userSignedInStatus(isSignedIn)' // observe the user in/out
  ],
```

Add a Function

```
_userSignedInStatus: function (isSignedIn) {
 if (isSignedIn === false) {
   this.page = 'view404'; // redirect the user to another page
                          // import an element that cover the view
 } else {
                          //send a  log message to your database
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Joel. I will give it a try.